# Pass Function that is potentially a Null Reference Exception as a parameter

Tags: c#

I'd like to write a helper method that takes a func and a second parameter T, and attempts to invoke it.  If a Null Reference Exception occurs, return T (second parameter).  If it's successful, return the result of the func passed in.  So instead of:

```
tableRow[rowNum, fieldNamePos].Value != null ? tableRow[rowNum, fieldNamePos].Value.ToString() : "";
```

I could write

```
Helper.GetDefaultIfNull(tableRow[rowNum, fieldNamePos].Value.ToString,"")
```

Which I believe is more concise and less code. Here's what I have in the GetDefaultIfNull method:

```
public T GetDefaultIfNull<T>(Func<T> funcToInvoke, T defaultValue)
{
    T result;
    try
    {
       result = stringFunc.Invoke();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
       result = defaultValue;
    }

    return result;
}
```

When I run tests, this works correctly when passing in a non null reference, however when passing in a null reference, it throws an error when calling the method so it seems to be invoking the function while passing it into the method?  Here is the test code:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void NULL_EXCEPTION_return_default()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = null;

        //Func<string> stringFunc = ; 
        var defaultValue = "";
        var result = new Helper().GetDefaultIfNull(sb.ToString, defaultValue);

        Assert.AreEqual(defaultValue, result);
    }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: do you know the [`??` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) ? If I understand, it basically do what you want to achieve.

Comment: like so?
try
{
     return functionToCall()
}
catch (exception)
{
    return T;
}'

If that's what you mean, that's 8 lines of code for each time I do this.

Comment: i do know the ?? but this involves a method call on this object. i need to make sure its not null before i call a method on that object

Comment: Throwing/expecting `NullReferenceException` is often considered sign of broken/incomplete code. You'll make your life easier if you don't eat such exception and write code that does proper checks. You may also use [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) to avoid such conditions.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why not just use a default value that can have `toString` called on it? `(tableRow[rowNum, fieldNamePos].Value ?? defaultValue).toString()` is more concise *and* more expressive.

Comment: I'm using a 3rd party library that reads excel and if the value of the cell is blank, Cell.Value == null, which is a pain.  Perhaps the developer of this library has ways around this but this is more of a "What am I doing wrong"/learning experience question. Completely agree with you though

Comment: zzzzBov that's a great solution.  I actually just created an extension method for the ExcelRange object that I think I'm going to go with.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because by accessing a method this way on an object you're *still* dereferencing a null pointer. In other words, this line:

```
sb.ToString
```

is attempting to access a member (`ToString`) of a null reference (`sb`).

Changing the way you're calling your function would fix the problem:

```
var result = new Helper().GetDefaultIfNull(() => sb.ToString(), defaultValue);
```

That is, create a new Lambda and invoke that instead. The `NullReferenceException` you're expecting in your method will be thrown, caught, and handled the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The null reference is occurring when attempting to find the function, i.e, if `sb` is null then `sb.ToString` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.  I would suggest that you might want to do something like

```
public T GetDefaultIfNull<T>(object value, T defaultValue)
{
     return value == null 
             ? defaultValue
             : Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

Then call it as

```
Helper.GetDefaultIfNull(tableRow[rowNum, fieldNamePos].Value, "");
```

Now, this assumes that the value is convertible to `T` but I'm assuming that you know what type it should be and the conversion operation would either be a no-op or you'd know that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
public T GetDefaultIfNull<T>(Func<T> funcToInvoke, T defaultValue)
{
    T result;
    try
    {
        result = stringFunc.Invoke();
        if (result == null)
        {
             //Do something with result as it is not null
        }
        else{
            result = defaultValue;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Message;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have an alternative where you do a simple sanity check

```
public T GetDefaultIfNull<T>(Func<T> funcToInvoke, T defaultValue) {
    T result;
    if (funcToInvoke == null) {
        return result = defaultValue;
    }
    try {
        result = funcToInvoke.Invoke();
    } catch (Exception) {
        result = defaultValue;
    }

    return result;
}
```

And the test method is below.

```
//running a NUnit test
[Test]
public void NULL_EXCEPTION_return_default() {
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    var defaultValue = string.Empty;
    var result = new TestHelper().GetDefaultIfNull(sb.ToString, defaultValue);

    Assert.AreEqual(defaultValue, result);
}
```